# Pyspark: parallelize XGBoost across cluster nodes

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, xgboost

I'm trying to run XGBoost models distributed onto multiple nodes on a Databricks cluster. I.e., run a model on each node, not a single model across multiple nodes. I've written a function that takes in an int, loads some data, and then trains an xgboost model. The code runs but it appears that it is not running in parallel and not utilizing all cores. Running using parallelize takes about 20-30 minutes. Running the function on its own without parallelize takes about 8-10 minutes for 2 models. Here's my function that I'm using.

```
import xgboost as xgb
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, save_npz, load_npz

def train_xgboost_bootstrap_models(n: int):
  train_id = pd.read_pickle(f'/dbfs/Data/01/train_id_{n}.pickle' ).sort_values(by='row_index')
  sp_train = load_npz(f'/dbfs/Data/01/sp_train_{n}.npz')
  id_oob = pd.read_pickle(f'/dbfs/Data/01/id_oob_{n}.pickle' ).sort_values(by='row_index')
  sp_oob = load_npz(f'/dbfs/Data/01/sp_oob_{n}.npz')
  
  dmat_train = xgb.DMatrix(sp_train, label=train_id.y.values)
  dmat_oob = xgb.DMatrix(sp_oob, label=id_oob.y.values)
  
  param = {
  'objective'               : "reg:tweedie",
  'tweedie_variance_power'  : 1.5,
  'eval_metric'             : "rmse",
  'tree_method'             : 'hist',
  'booster'                 : 'gbtree'
  }
  nrounds = 100
  model = xgb.train(params=param, dtrain = dmat_train, num_boost_round=nrounds, evals=[(dmat_train, 'train'), (dmat_oob, 'eval')])
  
  return model

models = sc.parallelize(list(range(2))).map(lambda x: train_xgboost_bootstrap_models(x)).collect()

# Compare to
train_xgboost_bootstrap_models(n=0)
train_xgboost_bootstrap_models(n=1)
```

Comment: What is the Databricks Cluster Config? How many nodes does it have?
You might be better off using Python threading to parallelize it